# The docs of firebase-app-indexing are silent on Flutter implementation

Tags: flutter, firebase-app-indexing

Is it just a matter of following the android and iOS settings or are there ways to make it a bit easier for those who are building apps in Flutter?

An example of a Flutter implementation of firebase-app-indexing would be fantastic.

Comment: From the official [github](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/FlutterFire.md) page it seems there's no first party plugin for Firebase App Indexing.

Comment: @shadowsheep how about now in October 2019 ?

Comment: @anunixercoder Nope. You can follow this [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/361) to stay in touch with this feature request.